# Killing a process which runs with a specific commandline using taskkill command

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, tasks

The process I'm trying to kill is:

`rundll32.exe aeinv.dll,UpdateSoftwareInventory`

However, I don't want to kill all instances of rundll32.exe, only the ones started with the "aeinv.dll,UpdateSoftwareInventory" commandline.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following:
In PowerShell use the command:
`Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'rundll32.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine,ProcessId`

This will give you back a list of all of the rundll32.exe processes running along with their CLI arguments.

Then use the ProcessID of that particular one to kill it, whether via Task Manager, `Stop-Process -Id <ProcessID>` in PowerShell, or `taskkill -PID <ProcessID>` in an administrative command prompt.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't return anything for commandline, only gives me processid

Comment: Are you running Powershell/Powershell ISE as Admin?

Comment: I had to include `/F` and `/T` flags to  kill some orphaned `rundll32.exe` processes